# Python - sort list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list in this format:

```
a = ["1.mp4", "10.mp4", "100.mp4", "2.mp4", "20.mp4", "200.mp4"]
```

I have to sort the above list in ascending order.

My code:

```
def ascend(a):
    a.sort()
    return a

a = ["1.mp4", "10.mp4", "100.mp4", "2.mp4", "20.mp4", "200.mp4"]
print(ascend(a))
```

My Output:

```
['1.mp4', '10.mp4', '100.mp4', '2.mp4', '20.mp4', '200.mp4']
```

And the actual Output should be

```
['1.mp4', '2.mp4', '10.mp4', '20.mp4', '100.mp4', '200.mp4']
```

Comment: While this is a duplicate, it's useful for OP to understand what's wrong with his code. He has shown an attempt at his problem, and so his question is a valid one nonetheless

Answer (score 9):

The problem is it's sorting lexicographically not numerically so `'10' < '2'` in this case. Add a sort key:

```
>>> a = ["1.mp4", "10.mp4", "100.mp4", "2.mp4", "20.mp4", "200.mp4"]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x[:-4]))
['1.mp4', '2.mp4', '10.mp4', '20.mp4', '100.mp4', '200.mp4']
```

The `key` parameter takes in a function, which deals with each element of `a`. We are telling Python to sort each element by first removing the `.mp4` of the string, then converting the string to an integer, and sorting numerically.

Comment: `rstrip` hey? Let's hope a filename isn't `444.mp4` then (or anything with 4's immediately preceding ".mp4" - else a nice little subtle sorting error/exception!)

Comment: So `a = ["1.mp4", "10.mp4", "100.mp4", "24.mp4", "20.mp4", "200.mp4"]` will sort incorrectly, and `a = ['1.mp4', '2.mp4', '10.mp4', '20.mp4', '100.mp4', '200.mp4', '444.mp4']` will raise a `ValueError`...

Comment: @JonClements Wow ok I had absolutely no idea `rstrip` performed like that... TIL

Answer (score 3):

Split on (.) and convert to int

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
```

Comment: Use of `os.path.splitext` would be more correct here.